# Getting elements within a numpy array by using a list of tuples as indices in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

I have a list of tuples (of integers), which is quite long to loop over. I also have a numpy array. I want to get the element given by each tuple in the list, without having to loop over the list. Something like this:

```
mySum = np.sum(myArray(myList))
```

which of course doesn't work. Is there a way for me to make this happen?
The list looks something like this: `myList = [(1,2,2),(0,0,2),...,(100,122,200)]`.

`myArray` is a 3d numpy array.

Comment: Is `myArray` a numpy array with three dimensions?

Comment: How does `myArray` look like?

Comment: @TillHoffmann Sorry, I forgot, see the edit.

Comment: @ozgur Sorry, I forgot, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the indices for each dimension and then slice the numpy array (assuming `myArray` is an array with three dimensions):

```
# Define the indices
myList = [(1,2,2), (0,0,2), (100,122,200), (3, 4, 5)]
# Define the array (just random numbers)
myArray = np.random.uniform(size=(101, 201, 201))
# Extract the indices
a, b, c = np.transpose(myList)
# Slice the numpy array and sum
mySum = np.sum(myArray[a, b, c])
```

Comment: What does `transpose` do exactly?

Comment: Transpose changes `myList` from an n-by-three array to a three-by-n array. Rather than a long list of three-tuples you end up with three lists of integers. You can find more information here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose